# How to get minimum date of a data within a same column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to get the minimum date and create auto generated `date_created` column where `upload_date` is same?

```
File Name |  Upload_Date
----------+---------
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-14 15:53:59
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-14 18:00:00
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-15 09:30:02
 blue.txt |  2021-07-14 11:20:11
 blue.txt |  2021-07-14 16:12:20
```

Expected result:

```
File Name |      Upload_Date       | date_created
----------+------------------------+--------------------
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-14 15:53:59   | 2021-07-14 15:53:59 
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-14 18:00:00   | 2021-07-14 15:53:59
 Log.csv  |  2021-07-15 09:30:02   | 2021-07-14 15:53:59
 blue.txt |  2021-07-14 11:20:11   | 2021-07-14 11:20:11
 blue.txt |  2021-07-14 16:12:20   | 2021-07-14 11:20:11
```

I'm using earlier version of MySQL in Xampp.

Thanks!

Comment: could probably try select min(upload_date) where file name = 'your filename' as a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for you,

```
update tablename as t1
INNER JOIN 
(select file_name, MIN(upload_date) min_date from tablename group by file_name) t2 
ON t1.file_name = t2.file_name
set t1.date_created = t2.min_date;
```

replace tablename with your Table Name.